# can I set a value in redis from the redis server's current system time?

Tags: redis

that is, I'd like to append to a sorted-set something like:

"set1" -> [1371772258, 1371772265, 1371772299, etc.]

but I don't want to send in the time values from my server.  I want to get a consistant timestamp from one server's clock, the server redis is running on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [the TIME command](http://redis.io/commands/time) (available with Redis 2.6). It returns two values: the epoch in seconds, and the number of micro-seconds.

You can call it directly from the application. In that case, 2 roundtrips will be required (one to execute TIME, one to update the zset).

Answer (score 4):

*This solution works since Redis version 2.6.0*

There could be easy solution if Redis provide Lua `os.time` function, but it doesn't.

So I've invented some hack. We can set `EXPIREAT` in future, and then with `TTL` we will know current unix timestamp.

Here is proof of concept. Of course you can do at least 2 optimizations: set `future` key once in your redis database and then just read its ttl in lua script, and obviously use `evalsha` instead of `eval`.

**zaddts.lua**

```lua
local future_ts, cur_ts, zkey, zmember

future_ts = 2000000000
redis.call('setnx', 'future', 1)
redis.call('expireat', 'future', future_ts)
cur_ts = future_ts - redis.call('ttl', 'future')
zkey = KEYS[1]
zmember = KEYS[2]
return redis.call('zadd', zkey, cur_ts, zmember)
```

Example of oneliner with hardcoded timestamp:

```lua
return redis.call('zadd', KEYS[1], 2000000000 - redis.call('ttl', 'future'), KEYS[2])
```

**example-client.php**

```php
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);

$r = new Redis();
$r->connect('localhost');

$script = file_get_contents('zaddts.lua');

$r->eval($script, array('events', 'event1'), 2);
sleep(1);
$r->eval($script, array('events', 'event2'), 2);
print_r($r->zrange('events', 0, -1, $withscore = true));
/* Output:
Array
(
    [event1] => 1371777755
    [event2] => 1371777756
)
*/
```

**UPD:** [facepalm] I didn't see `TIME` command. With it lua script became much simpler:

**zaddts.lua**

```lua
local time_full, time_sec, zkey, zmember

zkey = KEYS[1]
zmember = KEYS[2]

time_full = redis.call('time')
time_sec = tonumber(time_full[1])

return redis.call('zadd', zkey, time_sec, zmember)
```

**UPD 2:** Code with `time` call doesn't work due to the redis lua scripting restrictions ([Scripts as pure functions](http://redis.io/commands/eval)):

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> eval "return redis.call('zadd', 'events', redis.call('time')[1], 'some-event')" 0
(error) ERR Error running script (call to f_426eeadf424497fc04eb8f06efac0553f3212660): Write commands not allowed after non deterministic commands
```

So first version of code (with `ttl`) still makes sense.

Comment: Good remark: I forgot TIME cannot be called from Lua due to master/slave replication constraints.

Comment: That said, your proposal has exactly the same problem. If you replicate to a slave, you will have a discrepancy between master and slave regarding the timestamps ...

Comment: Perhaps ... it looks like a flaw in the logic found by Salvatore to prevent non deterministic data to be replicated.

Comment: according to the EXPIRE docs http://redis.io/commands/expire, it seems like expiry DEL is sent from master to slave. Although in this thread http://grokbase.com/t/gg/redis-db/12b519d6ga/lua-script-execution-time using PTTL doesn't seem to be very recommended..